# Bootstrap layouts - Flexible columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am trying to implement bootstrap layouts for my dashboard application.
Here is code that I have found on Internet that I am adapting.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--panel-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works great, except that when I add some content to a column the column is not adjusting to the width of the content. What do I need to do to make column resizing itself?

Thanks

Comment: you'll nee to add some more tags try col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 on your first div and col-sm-6 col-xs-12 on your next two. you should see responsiveness

Comment: It is somewhat better because the content is not gong out of column's boundaries but the column itself is not getting bigger to accommodate the width of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is based on a 12 column grid system, your parent div was saying "divide the screen into 3 boxes" (col-md-4). You could replace that with a few different options to make the divs take up the remainder of the space. I chose row in this example but you can experiment with col-md-12 or col-xs-12.

Updated my fiddle with a more complete example, try re-sizing the display window:

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7933/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remember to re-size your window frequently to see how bootstrap reacts

Comment: Yes! Great, works as expected. What helped the most was using row.

Comment: Glad it helped, remember to accept this as the answer if helped solve your problem. And don't forget to checkout bootstraps docs, they are very easy to read: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/